# Which site is my question appropriate for? (Practical method to form/shape nalgene bottle)

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm not sure which site is appropriate for my question. I was considering chemistry, then physics, then engineering, but I don't want to be sent to "downvote hell".

Any suggestions?

Question:

---

Title: Practical method to form/shape nalgene bottle

About a year ago, I lost my Eddie Bauer water bottle, similar to this one:

[image: eddie bauer bottle]

I've been trying to find a replacement, but it seems they've discontinued the model.

With that in mind, I'm planning on purchasing this bottle:

[image: nalgene bottle]

Unfortunately, the nalgene doesn't have the molded grip which so endeared me to my original bottle.

So..I'd like to mold them in!

The amazon page says the bottle is suitable for liquids in the range of 
-40 to 212 degrees Fahrenheit 
(  ttp://www.amazon.com/Nalgene-Tritan-Mouth-Bottle-1-Quart/dp/B001NCDE8O/)

My question is:

Should I heat the whole bottle up and indent the desired grip with a cool implement, heat up the implement and press it into the bottle, or some other solution?

An ideal answer would not only provide justification for the proposed method, but also suggestions on the most feasible way to enact it.

Comment: Not sure which site, and I'm no scientist, but wouldn't such an action deteriorate and weaken the structure of whatever material it's made of? (Hmm, I guess that's what you want to ask..) Have a look [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#lifearts) and use the tabs to select other categories. Maybe DIY or Lifehacks might be suitable, but I don't use those sites so you'd need to check their Help Center and Metas (or someone might answer you here)

Comment: I would say Great Outdoors since it involves outdoor equipment.

Comment: DIY, despite its short name, is strictly about Home Improvement. They don't even accept questions about appliances, so this is not going to fly there. @James

Comment: Lifehacks may be okay?

Comment: I wasn't aware lifehacks existed! That's definitely the site for me :)

Comment: Oof...I got sent to [downvote hell anyway](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/8007/practical-method-to-form-shape-nalgene-bottle)